# Query Result from Database requested from Mobile App

Tags: php, api, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui

I'm connecting hybrid app to the API of the web app to query certain data after search request by the user. I'm using Onsen UI to build the app.

The API code at the server side should return the merchant that the user searched for by it's name. The result should be only 1 merchant (restaurant name)

```
public function actionSearchMerchant()
{       
    if (!isset($this->data['merchant'])){
        $this->msg=$this->t("Restaurant Name is required");
        $this->output();
    }

    if (isset($_GET['debug'])){
        dump($this->data);
    }

    if ( !empty($this->data['merchant'])){

            $DbExt=new DbExt; 
            $DbExt->qry("SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1");

            $total_records=0;
            $data='';

            $and="AND status='active' AND is_ready='2' ";

            $services_filter='';
            if (isset($this->data['services'])){
                $services=!empty($this->data['services'])?explode(",",$this->data['services']):false;                   
                if ($services!=false){
                    foreach ($services as $services_val) {
                        if(!empty($services_val)){
                           $services_filter.="'$services_val',";
                        }
                    }
                    $services_filter=substr($services_filter,0,-1);
                    if(!empty($services_filter)){
                       $and.=" AND service IN ($services_filter)";
                    }
                }
            }

            $filter_cuisine='';
            if (isset($this->data['cuisine_type'])){
                $cuisine_type=!empty($this->data['cuisine_type'])?explode(",",$this->data['cuisine_type']):false;
                if ($cuisine_type!=false){
                    $x=1;
                    foreach (array_filter($cuisine_type) as $cuisine_type_val) {                            
                        if ( $x==1){
                           $filter_cuisine.=" LIKE '%\"$cuisine_type_val\"%'";
                        } else $filter_cuisine.=" OR cuisine LIKE '%\"$cuisine_type_val\"%'";
                        $x++;
                    }           
                    if (!empty($filter_cuisine)){
                       $and.=" AND (cuisine $filter_cuisine)";
                     }          
                }
            }

            $rname=$this->data['merchant'];

            $stmt="SELECT * FROM
                   {{view_merchant}}
                   WHERE
                   restaurant_name LIKE '%\"$rname\"%'

                   SELECT a.*,count(*) as total_records FROM
                   {{view_merchant}} a
                   WHERE
                   restaurant_name LIKE '%\"$rname\"%'
                   $and
                   LIMIT 0,100
            ";


            if (isset($_GET['debug'])){
               dump($stmt); 
            }

            if ( $res=$DbExt->rst($stmt)){      

                $stmtc="SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total_records";
                if ($resp=$DbExt->rst($stmtc)){                     
                    $total_records=$resp[0]['total_records'];
                }                   

                $this->code=1;
                $this->msg=$this->t("Successful");

                foreach ($res as $val) {        

                    $minimum_order=getOption($val['merchant_id'],'merchant_minimum_order');
                    if(!empty($minimum_order)){
                        $minimum_order=displayPrice(getCurrencyCode(),prettyFormat($minimum_order));                    
                    }

                    $delivery_fee=getOption($val['merchant_id'],'merchant_delivery_charges');
                    if (!empty($delivery_fee)){
                        $delivery_fee=displayPrice(getCurrencyCode(),prettyFormat($delivery_fee));
                    }

                    /*check if mechant is open*/
                    $open=AddonMobileApp::isMerchantOpen($val['merchant_id']);

                    /*check if merchant is commission*/
                    $cod=AddonMobileApp::isCashAvailable($val['merchant_id']);
                    $online_payment='';

                    $tag='';
                    $tag_raw='';
                    if ($open==true){                           
                        $tag=$this->t("open");
                        $tag_raw='open';
                        if ( getOption( $val['merchant_id'] ,'merchant_close_store')=="yes"){
                            $tag=$this->t("close");
                            $tag_raw='close';
                        }
                        if (getOption( $val['merchant_id'] ,'merchant_preorder')==1){
                            $tag=$this->t("pre-order");
                            $tag_raw='pre-order';
                        }
                    } else  {
                        $tag=$this->t("close");
                        $tag_raw='close';
                        if (getOption( $val['merchant_id'] ,'merchant_preorder')==1){
                            $tag=$this->t("pre-order");
                            $tag_raw='pre-order';
                        }
                    }                   


                    $data[]=array(
                      'merchant_id'=>$val['merchant_id'],
                      'restaurant_name'=>$val['restaurant_name'],
                      'address'=>$val['street']." ".$val['city']." ".$val['state']." ".$val['post_code'],
                      'ratings'=>Yii::app()->functions->getRatings($val['merchant_id']),
                      'cuisine'=>AddonMobileApp::prettyCuisineList($val['cuisine']),
                      'delivery_fee'=>$delivery_fee,                          
                      'minimum_order'=>$minimum_order,
                      'delivery_est'=>getOption($val['merchant_id'],'merchant_delivery_estimation'),
                      'is_open'=>$tag,
                      'tag_raw'=>$tag_raw,
                      'payment_options'=>array(
                        'cod'=>$cod,
                        'online'=>$online_payment
                      ),                         
                      'logo'=>AddonMobileApp::getMerchantLogo($val['merchant_id']),
                      'offers'=>AddonMobileApp::getMerchantOffers($val['merchant_id'])
                    );
                }                   

                $this->details=array(
                  'total'=>$total_records,
                  'data'=>$data
                );

            } else $this->msg=$this->t("No restaurant found");
         } else $this->msg=$this->t("Error has occurred failed restaurant info");
    } else $this->msg=$this->t("Restaurant Name is required");
    $this->output();
}
```

Basically I'm sending a parameter names "merchant" from the app that the API should get and search a table into the database called "view_merchant" column "restaurant_name" and compare the name requested by the one in the database then return it back to the app as found.

EDIT I added the JS function

```
var search_restaurant;
var search_cuisine;
var search_food;

    $("#r").val( getStorage("search_restaurant") );
    $("#c").val( getStorage("search_cuisine") );
    $("#f").val( getStorage("search_food") );

function searchMerchantName()
{           

  var r = $('#r').val();  

  /*clear all storage*/
  setStorage("search_restaurant",r);   
  removeStorage('merchant_id');
  removeStorage('shipping_address');  
  removeStorage('merchant_id');
  removeStorage('transaction_type');
  removeStorage('merchant_logo');
  removeStorage('order_total');
  removeStorage('merchant_name');
  removeStorage('total_w_tax');
  removeStorage('currency_code');
  removeStorage('paymet_desc');
  removeStorage('order_id');   
  removeStorage('order_total_raw');   
  removeStorage('cart_currency_symbol');     
  removeStorage('paypal_card_fee');   

  if(r!=""){
      var options = {     
          merchant:r,                 
          closeMenu:true,
          animation: 'slide'          
       };            
      menu.setMainPage('searchMerchants.html',options);

  } else{
     onsenAlert(   getTrans('Restaurant Name is required','merchant_is_required')  );
  }
}

function searchCuisine()
{           

  var c = $('#c').val();  

  /*clear all storage*/
  setStorage("search_cuisine",c);   
  removeStorage('merchant_id');
  removeStorage('shipping_address');  
  removeStorage('merchant_id');
  removeStorage('transaction_type');
  removeStorage('merchant_logo');
  removeStorage('order_total');
  removeStorage('merchant_name');
  removeStorage('total_w_tax');
  removeStorage('currency_code');
  removeStorage('paymet_desc');
  removeStorage('order_id');   
  removeStorage('order_total_raw');   
  removeStorage('cart_currency_symbol');     
  removeStorage('paypal_card_fee');   

  if(c!=""){
      var options = {     
          cuisine:c,                  
          closeMenu:true,
          animation: 'slide'          
       };            
      menu.setMainPage('searchCuisine.html',options);

  } else{
     onsenAlert(   getTrans('Cuisine Type is required','cuisine_is_required')  );
  }
}

function searchFood()
{           

  var f = $('#f').val();  

  /*clear all storage*/
  setStorage("search_food",f);   
  removeStorage('merchant_id');
  removeStorage('shipping_address');  
  removeStorage('merchant_id');
  removeStorage('transaction_type');
  removeStorage('merchant_logo');
  removeStorage('order_total');
  removeStorage('merchant_name');
  removeStorage('total_w_tax');
  removeStorage('currency_code');
  removeStorage('paymet_desc');
  removeStorage('order_id');   
  removeStorage('order_total_raw');   
  removeStorage('cart_currency_symbol');     
  removeStorage('paypal_card_fee');   

  if(f!=""){
      var options = {     
          foodname:f,                 
          closeMenu:true,
          animation: 'slide'          
       };            
      menu.setMainPage('searchFood.html',options);

  } else{
     onsenAlert(   getTrans('Food Name is required','foodname_is_required')  );
  }
}

        case "searchmerchant-page": 
        $("#search-text").html( getStorage("search_restaurant") );
        callAjax("searchmerchant","merchant="+ getStorage("search_restaurant") );   

        break;

        case "searchcuisine-page":  
        $("#search-text").html( getStorage("search_cuisine") );
        callAjax("searchcuisine","cuisine="+ getStorage("search_cuisine") );    

        break;

        case "searchfood-page": 
        $("#search-text").html( getStorage("search_food") );
        callAjax("searchfood","foodname="+ getStorage("search_food") ); 

        break;

        case "page-home":                           
            geoComplete();

            search_address=getStorage("search_address");

            if (typeof search_address === "undefined" || search_address==null || search_address=="" ) { 
            } else {                                                
                setTimeout('$("#s").val(search_address)', 1000);
            }
            translatePage();        

            $("#s").attr("placeholder",  getTrans('Street Address,City,State','home_search_placeholder') );

            //Added for Restaurant Name Search

            search_restaurant=getStorage("search_restaurant");

            if (typeof search_restaurant === "undefined" || search_restaurant==null || search_restaurant=="" ) { 
            } else {                                                
                setTimeout('$("#r").val(search_restaurant)', 1000);
            }
            translatePage();        

            $("#r").attr("placeholder",  getTrans('Restaurant Name','restaurant_search_placeholder') );

            //Added for Cuisine Type

            search_cuisine=getStorage("search_cuisine");

            if (typeof search_cuisine === "undefined" || search_cuisine==null || search_cuisine=="" ) { 
            } else {                                                
                setTimeout('$("#c").val(search_cuisine)', 1000);
            }
            translatePage();        

            $("#c").attr("placeholder",  getTrans('Cuisine Type','cuisine_search_placeholder') );

            //Added for Food Type

            search_food=getStorage("search_food");

            if (typeof search_food === "undefined" || search_food==null || search_food=="" ) { 
            } else {                                                
                setTimeout('$("#f").val(search_food)', 1000);
            }
            translatePage();        

            $("#f").attr("placeholder",  getTrans('Food Name','food_search_placeholder') );

        break;

function searchResultCallBack(address)
{
    search_address=address; 
}

function searchMerchantsCallBack(merchant)
{
    search_restaurant=merchant; 
}

function searchCuisineCallBack(cuisine)
{
    search_cuisine=cuisine; 
}

function searchFoodCallBack(foodname)
{
    search_food=foodname;   
}
```

Comment: What do you need help with?  Do you need the PHP page and an example of calling that from JS?  This isn't specific to Onsen, so I am confused as to what help you need.

Comment: @Munsterlander yes it's not related to Onsen it's PHP I'll update the question with the JS functions to check. What I need is query the data requested and post it back to the user.

Comment: How do you want the data returned JSON object or a string?

Comment: I posted the SQL statement and it just depends on how you want to return the data.  JSON objects are the most common.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement will be:

```
SELECT * FROM view_merchant WHERE lower(restaurant_name)=?
```

You will want to `toLowerCase()` your passed value `$this->data['merchant']` so you are finding the restaurant regardless of casing.  The only issue is that this will return multiple records if there are ones with the same name.